# Remove text colour of navbar links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have created a navbar using Bootstrap. I have used `.bg-danger` to add a red background. For some reason, the navbar links appear blue and not black as expected since `.navbar-light` is used. How do I prevent the links from showing in blue font?

Here is the html for the navbar:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="nav navbar-expand-md bg-danger navbar-light nav-tabs sticky-top justify-content-center">
        <a class="nav-link" href='/home/'>Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href='/feed/'>Newsfeed</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href='/profiles/'>View Candidates</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href='/register/'>Register</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href='/elections/'>Elections</a>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 things you need to correct:

1. Put your nav links into a div with the `navbar-nav` class
2. Add the `nav-item` class to each nav link

**This approach avoids unnecessary css hacks.**

Here's the working code snippet (click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="nav navbar-expand-md bg-danger navbar-dark nav-tabs sticky-top justify-content-center">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href='/home/'>Home</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href='/feed/'>Newsfeed</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href='/profiles/'>View Candidates</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href='/register/'>Register</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href='/elections/'>Elections</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your anchor tag to add style as below ??

style='color:black'

```
<a class="nav-link" style='color:black' href='/home/'>Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think right now your links are taking up the default values provided in the bootstrap's default css. You can overwrite the link colors by using below code in your css and make sure it comes after bootstrap's default css.

```
.bg-danger .nav-link {
  color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about :
when is **active**:

```
class="nav-link active text-secondary"
```

when is **inactive**:

```
class="nav-link text-body"
```